# Having a SVG file in a img link display on IE10

Tags: svg

I have a basic html file. In the file I have an image tag which references a SVG file.
When I view the file in IE10 the page remains blank rather then showing the expected vector image.
The SVG file was made with Inkscape.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <img src="Images/MyLOGO.svg" width="400"/>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

What is the best way to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Start by removing `runat="server"` for a form without any input elements

Comment: That will be ignored on an html page but I have removed it with no change in results.

Comment: Since problem was with input file (see answer posted by OP), which wasn't attached as an example. This question isn't constructive for the site.

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be because in IE9+, Chrome and Safari won’t apply stylesheet rules to the SVG if they’re defined in a separate CSS file.

Comment: There is no style sheet involved. And I have removed the width value with no effect.

Comment: can you do a fiddle so I can try and debug?

Answer (score 0):

The SVG file must have been invalid. I have replaced it with a different SVG file and all works as expected.